# How to define where the cursor goes in an XML-file when i press F12 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, ide, settings

I have to work on a rather lengthy XML-File. The structure of the file is so, that you have the tags like this:

```
<foo id="bar">
<!-- stuff -->
</foo>
```

which are then later referenced this way once or more often:

```
<foo RefId="bar"/>
```

It would be immensely helpful for my work flow, when I just could highlight the RefId parameter, and press F12 and it would jump to the "definition". Is there a way to set up Visual Studio code in a way to work within XML files analogous to a function call in C or Python?

I tried seraching the settings, finding another plugin and searched the internet for a solution, to no awail.ü

Comment: If `refId` is some XML standard attribute with special meaning, then maybe, but otherwise, I find it doubtful that you'll get something like this out-of-box even with a general XML extension. You could write you own extension.

Answer (score 0):

Is your definition in the same file as your RefId tag?
If so, highlight the RefId and ctrl+D, it will jump to the next "RefId".
Provided you dont have it referenced elsewhere, it should be your definition.

Comment: It is one file, yes. There can be mutliple Tags with the same RefID though, and the definition is usually before teh refrence, but not always

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).